# Cloud Firestore security rules: how to check if property exists?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to check is property exists in document in store.
`allow update, delete: if resource.data.uid;`
in code above i have error "Property uid is undefined on object.", so how i can check is `uid` in data?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  I suggesting explaining in more detail what you're trying to accomplish, which includes showing the query that you're trying to protect, the contents of the database at that location, and more details about the rules you're trying to write (not just the one line you have now).

Comment: i need to allow deleting, updating if target document doesnt has property uid( in javascript for example would be just ```if(resource.data.uid) { // if true} else { //if false }``` , but here in firebase rules got an error when document doesnt has a ```uid``` instead of getting false

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To check if the document contains a specific field, I use `in`:

```
allow update, delete: if 'uid' in resource.data;
```

As noted in the comments, if you want to check whether field is **not** in the data, you need to use parentheses:

```
allow update, delete: if !('fieldname' in resource.data);
```

Comment: just one correction: need to use resource.data.keys()

Comment: @A.Melnyk according to the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map the in operator works on maps aswell as on lists. So calling keys() is not required

Comment: is there a way to deny this afirmation. I want to check if the property does NOT exists

Comment: Yeah, `!'uid' in resource.data` should work for write and get operations. If you're having trouble making it work with your use-case, open a new question with the minimal code+rules+data with which any of us can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I had to do `!('uid' in resource.data)` within a function.