# Firestore - Error on security rule I cannot figure out

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The following code produces an error in firestore. Not a denial, an error. I am trying to set a read permission if there is a parameter called "test" is set on the documents

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /designs/{design} {
      allow create:  if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.designer == true;
      allow read: if resource.data.test==true;
    }

  }

}
```

This works, so I know that the error is something wrong on the read line

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /designs/{design} {
      allow create:  if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.designer == true;
      allow read: if true;
    }

  }

}
```

This seems like it should be unbearably simple and it is incredibly frustrating that I can't get any info on what is wrong here.

Comment: I think you're getting the error because the field doesn't exist in the document and `resource.data.test` results in nothing. To check it a field exists, try this solution posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56778742/cloud-firestore-security-rules-how-to-check-is-property-exists

Comment: Good point, but there are only two documents in the collection right now and both have the field.